# alternative to Resharper "go to file" and "go to implementation" features

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, developer-tools

Does anybody know a **light** plug-in that do (same as Resharper) go to implementation and the quick search for a file where you just insert few characters and it shows the matches? I just want to get rid of Resharper cause it slows me down a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the original question, as per [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2008/08/02/visual-studio-trick-to-quickly-find-any-file-in-solution.aspx) by Andrew Arnott, you can use Ctrl+/ to move the cursor to the Find text box in the toolbar, then type ">of" and start typing file names. The matching files will appear as you type.

Using the ">" prefix causes the find text box to act as the command window would.

(Note that the Ctrl+/ short-cut may be overridden by ReSharper to comment a line of code, so this short-cut only works with ReSharper uninstalled.)

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  I use ReSharper and it uses about 400mb of RAM.  I would consider that pretty low usage.

Maybe you can look into Productivity Power Tools (I don't use it).

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/

Comment: I'm working on a big solution with few projects (around 20/30) but lot of classes and I had to disable the PPT because of incompatibility issues with ReSharper.. I never use ReSharper in the past and I found it in this company I recently joined.

Comment: When you said that it "slows you down", I just assumed you meant your pc's performance.  Do you mean that you are just not adept at using it?

Comment: I mean it freezes Visual Studio so I have to stare at my screen praying it finishes doing whatever is doing and I dont have to close and restart visual studio for the umpteenth time..

Comment: Do you think the freeze is the result of a compatibility problem?  I guess knowing your pc's specs would help.  Do you have plenty of RAM?

Comment: 64bit machine with 12GB is that enough?

Comment: @user813948 More than enough. Have you tried contacting JetBrains support at http://www.jetbrains.com/support/resharper/? There are ways to work around almost any kind of performance problems.